# move mailx account to gmail

Tags: gmail, mailx

I would love to know how to move my mails from mailx in linux to gmail. Say I want to move to gmail for my domain, and move over all my emails to the gmail account.

I wonder also are there any caveats?

Cheers

K

Comment: noone? please help me :)